# JavaScript namespace in Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, module-pattern

I was reading [How Good C# Habits can Encourage Bad JavaScript Habits](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/) article about creating `namespace` and modular pattern but I don't understand the reason to use `$` and `jQuery` to create the namespace. Look at this code:

```
(function( skillet, $, undefined ) {
    //Private Property
    var isHot = true;

    //Public Property
    skillet.ingredient = "Bacon Strips";

    //Public Method
    skillet.fry = function() {
        var oliveOil;

        addItem( "\t\n Butter \n\t" );
        addItem( oliveOil );
        console.log( "Frying " + skillet.ingredient );
    };

    //Private Method
    function addItem( item ) {
        if ( item !== undefined ) {
            console.log( "Adding " + $.trim(item) );
        }
    }    
}( window.skillet = window.skillet || {}, jQuery ));
```

Why is it sending `$` as parameter and then calling it with `jQuery`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I don't think that question is the clearest one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load the jQuery library, it binds two global symbols to a reference to the main function: "jQuery" and "$". Some other libraries also want to use "$", however, so jQuery provides a way to unbind "$" and restore it to whatever it was prior to loading jQuery. By using the technique in your example, you can use "$" in the code whether or not the global "$" refers to jQuery.

*edit* — that very article you referenced explains it similarly:

> The second argument passed [is] jQuery. The benefit of this is that the named parameter is referenced as $, which allows us to refer to jQuery as $ within the Anonymous Function without having to worry that it will conflict with the $ declared in other JavaScript libraries. This is a common practice that you will most likely run across when looking at well written jQuery code.

Comment: Sorry for stupid question but If I don't want to use jQuery at all do I still need it?

Comment: with this approach it'll be guaranteed that if I use `$` inside my namespace I will have jQuery called. And if I don't want to use jQuery in my module I can simply remove the parameter and `jQuery` together right? Is it correct?

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery, then the example is not relevant. If you do use it, then yes, with this trick "$" is guaranteed to be a reference to the global jQuery.  If you don't want to use it, just leave out the second parameter.